# Updating a Server Side Text File via Android

Tags: java, android, server-side

I'm building an app that needs to periodically append lines to a server side text file. So far, the best way I've come up with for doing this is using the Dropbox API, where the user has to download the text file, update it, and then upload it back - obviously this is not ideal. What would be the best (free) way to do something like this? I'd like a solution where I don't have to personally host a server, but can use some third party cloud (like Dropbox).

Comment: my way was creating a Home webservice and create text file for every user. for modifying this text file use ws methods.

Comment: You can use Google Drive.

Comment: Wouldn't I be doing the same thing with Google Drive - downloading, updating, and then uploading back?

Comment: I don't think you have any choice if you don't want your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [Android Backup Service](http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html) seems appropriate for this, and is free.